# Windows update scheduled BIOS update on my ASUS laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bios, windows-update, asus-laptop

I’ve updated my Windows 10 with Windows Update, then went to optional updates, and updated the drivers there also (there was an ASUSTeK Firmware update, which made me suspicious and I left it off). Then restarted laptop, and decided to update the ASUSTeK Firmware also. It asked for restart, and I restarted the laptop. Then at the very beginning it said something like “BIOS will be updated in 60 seconds” and there was Yes/No option. I chose No and the system booted into Windows again. Now there’s a “Restart required (Your PC needs to be restarted to finish setting up this device: System Firmware)” notification in the Windows notification area. I suppose that I’ll get the Yes/No option again if I restart/turn off and turn on my laptop again. Also, in Device Manager, there’s “System Firmware” entry with the exclamation mark inside a yellow triangle under Firmware.

I don’t want the BIOS to be updated. I want to somehow cancel the update.

My laptop is ASUS X509JA. I suppose it can be completely bricked with the update?

Is the update written on my SSD or on the BIOS itself? Will formatting/resetting my Windows 10 remove the scheduled update of BIOS?

Here's a screenshot of the prompt at the start of the laptop: http://kmpic.asus.com/images/2021/01/14/1145e2e9-bdcd-4e40-b300-dc5d8a3d9477.png (NOTE: This is a picture from the ASUS website, I'm not sure whether on my laptop it said "Easy Flash utility will allow..."

Any experience?

Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think the update can brick your computer? That is extremely unlikely. Most likely this firmware update is part of the security updates to mitigate the Spectre and Meltdown security issues (as far as I know the ONLY bios updates that are spread via Windows Update are for those) that affect most Intel CPU's. You WANT that update to be done, because that is the only way that problem can be fully patched. (Without updated bios, Windows can only prevent part of the possible attack vectors, not all of them.)

Comment: I messed up BIOS settings, partitions, Windows installations etc. I don't know whether my BIOS is Legacy/UEFI, whether my WIndows is installed in UEFI or Legacy mode, whether it recognizes the BIOS as UEFI but it's Legacy or the other way around. I have two Windows 10 installations on different partitions (dual-boot). The Windows Boot Manager of the newer OS which is default now is not showing graphically (it's black for 30 seconds) at start of laptop, but reacts to keyboard input and boots into second Windows. I don't know if my first and second installation are UEFI/Legacy (both differ maybe

Comment: I really don't want attack protection

Comment: @user1274541 There is often an option in the BIOS to save its settings to a USB drive - doing that is always a good idea before a BIOS update. So if you do that now, you won't have to worry so much about the update sneaking its way in at some time.

Comment: Firmware may not be a bios update, firmware could be for any piece of hardware on the motherboard, Windows does Not push out bios updates.

Comment: @moab Windows can do motherboard Bios updates. It is very rare and only for a small number of motherboards, but they do exist. I also think this wasn't for the motherboard in this case, but that doesn't really matter. The damage is already done.

Comment: Never seen one in all my years of using Windows on thousands of PC's since w95.

Comment: @AndrewMorton But if BIOS is bricked and can't be accessed, how would I restore the it from USB when I can't even enter BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

So you managed to really mess up your system.
With a broken dual-boot setup, partially applied Windows Updates and possible BIOS/EFI settings that don't match with the installed Windows version(s).
The aborted firmware update (I doubt it was actually system-bios, probably firmware for sound-card or network card) might actually have added a (temporary) 3rd boot entry to the startup that you prevented from running to completion, but that is still acting as the default boot.

That doesn't sound as something you can recover from without doing a full re-install of Windows 10.

Start by going into the BIOS settings and find the 'Reset to factory defaults' entry.
Try that first. It may allow you to boot again in the normal Windows system.
If that doesn't work it will at least have reset the Bios to a state that is suitable to do a fresh Windows 10 installation.

See what happens, but be prepared to re-install Windows from scratch.

PS.
Windows 10 really doesn't like dual-boot. Microsoft has never been fond of that and Windows 10 is the worst of all Windows versions when it comes to that. It totally expects to be the only OS on the hardware and have full control of the hardware.
It can be made to work, but you really have to be very, very careful not to break things.
If your really need a second OS consider installing that in a virtual machine. That is way easier and doesn't risk messing up your boot configuration.

Comment: Linux was installed by default when I bought it. I even reinstalled Windows 10 several times with dual-boot previously. If it says BIOS will update (from the screenshot) can it still be for the cards? I'd reinstall Windows from scratch right away, but I don't know whether it would remove the BIOS update prompt, or maybe break everything instead, since BIOS may be synced with Win now and expect the update file.